# How to dynamically translate in real time using the Google Translation API?

Tags: html, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-translate, translate

As the user types words, Google translate will dynamically in real-time translate the text on the other side.

Try it out at translate.google.com

Now I hope to mimic this feature on a translation website I'm building. I'm using React for the development.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you can use the [google translate API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/translate.googleapis.com/)

- Google provides great documentation and tutorials [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart?csw=1)

If you want to implement the asynchronous calls, you will need to make an [ajax request](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) after each word is typed

- React provides great documentation and tutorials [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html)